# Delete unused docker images from the internal docker registry of Openshift?

Tags: image, docker, openshift

What is the best way to delete the docker images form internal docker registry of openshift? The registry is taking a lot of space in openshift the thing I want is, When I delete the DeploymentConfig it should also delete the images associated with that form the internal docker registry of openshift so the storage problem will not occur but it's not happening? any way to work around this.

Comment: did you find a way to do it? i have the same problem ... :)

Comment: @ilias-sp use this ```oc adm prune images --keep-tag-revisions=1 --keep-younger-than=500m --confirm``` we are using this command in cron job. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the image cache on docker-registry using `oc adm images prune` as follows. Refer [Image Prune Conditions](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/pruning_resources.html#image-prune-conditions) for more details.

```
oc adm prune images --keep-tag-revisions=1 --keep-younger-than=500m --confirm
```

And if you can not take a free space enough, you try to clean docker images in docker storages on each node host using `docker` command.

```
--- Check the docker storage usage
# docker system df

--- Clear the unused docker images
# docker rmi $(docker images -q)

--- If you have unused containers, it can remove either.
# docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

Comment: `oc adm prune images` purges images "managed by OpenShift" (i.e., images with the annotation openshift.io/image.managed). this command wont help when you want to purge images that dont fall in this category. [link](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/pruning_resources.html#pruning-images)

Answer (score 0):

How to delete images from registry - you may use tool [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) for that.

Regarding cleaning up the registry - we use Sonatype Nexus as registry, it has number of built-in daily cleanup scripts, which work pretty nice - it cleans up image layers that are no more linked with any image tag.

If you have large number of outdated tags - you have to clean it up by yourself using the same Skopeo.